# Incorrect bounding boxes cropped

Tags: python, tensorflow, crop

This is my code to visualize bounding boxes on image:

```
 viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
  image_np_with_detections,
  detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
  (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
  detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
  category_index,
  use_normalized_coordinates=True,
  max_boxes_to_draw=200,
  min_score_thresh=.5,
  agnostic_mode=False,

 )
```

[image]

and this one is to crop bounding boxes after detection:

```
width=600
height=900

boxes = detections['detection_boxes']
ymin = int((boxes[0][0][0]*height))
xmin = int((boxes[0][0][1]*width))
ymax = int((boxes[0][0][2]*height))
xmax = int((boxes[0][0][3]*width))
print ("xmin: {} ".format(xmin),"ymin: {}".format(ymin),"xmax: {}".format(xmax),"ymax: {}".format(ymax))

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(image_path)
img2 = img.crop((xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax))
img2.save("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/UrduDetection/Croped_images/img8.jpg")
```

[image]

Which is not correct cropping as localization.

How to get correct cropped images of detected bounding boxes?

Answer (score 0):

PIL's `crop()`  function doesn't take the arguments you gave it. you should use it like `(left, top, right, bottom)` which in your case is :

```
img2 = img.crop((xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax))
```

or you could open the image as numpy array and using indexing to crop it.

```
img  = numpy.asarray(PIL.Image.open('test.jpg'))
img2 = img[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax, ...]
```

**EDIT**

I don't know what's inside your visualize function so I can't tell how it's working or not working. but by just looking at the numbers of your plot I can tell `xmin-xmax` should roughly be `200-620` not `143-420`. and also for `ymin-ymax` it's something around `510-560` instead of `779-856` that you're using.
you're giving a y range that doesn't exist, hence your black output.

you might be converting the coordinates outside visualize function the wrong way, your coordinates could be `xc,yc,w,h`  and you're treating it as `xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax` .

Comment: img2 = img.crop((xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)) it gives a blank black image.

Comment: I have numpy array of an image, when I tried img2 = img[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax];
img2.save("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/UrduDetection/Croped_images/img13.jpg") it says TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: @maryammehboob it says 'JpegImageFile'  is not subscriptable because it's not a numpy array. convert it to numpy arrary first.

Comment: @maryammehboob if you're getting a blank black image then your coordinates are wrong.

Comment: how can coordinates be wrong if bounding box appear on the image is right?

Comment: How we can use coordinates within visualize function?